# Roboto Draft Vs. Roboto

Tags: web-fonts, google-material-design, guides

So i have a question, i just hit inspect element on the Material Design Guide because i wanted to know the specs of the Dividers (I know those are very well explained in the guide) but i wanted to make a double check and suddenly in Family Fonts i read "roboto draft" so i google it and people said that it was Roboto2 before it was Renamed as "Roboto" as we know it.... And so my mind wonder, Why do they keep Roboto Draft on their Family Fonts library? is it lighter? is it a browser version thing? or there is a more technical explanation for that? ...

And the reason im asking this with such emphasis is because in my office we are developing a WebApp with all the Material Design Specs and well....im a very curious designer.

UPDATE: Robto Draft Regular Weight: 22kb | Roboto Regular weight: 145 kb

*So assuming that this weight difference is constant across the whole family then thats the reason.*

Thanks :)

Comment: Based on the file size I am guessing draft is a newer, lightweight version of the typeface. Google are continuously trying to decrease file sizes, with is another reason why they changed their logo. The SVG version of the new logo is smaller by over 50% (I think). Minuscule in the grand scheme of things but they seem to use marginal gains in an effort to improve download speeds across the web.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that they kept Roboto Draft in the Material Design Guide just to have a fallback. I know I keep previous versions of things hanging around so maybe they decided to keep it as an old version.

Comment: Well Roboto Draft is not The Fall Back... actually Roboto IS the fall back!